# Is there a difference between following import styles in python?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I was going through a codebase and noticed the following style of importing modules
`import torch.nn as nn`

In my personal work, I've always used the followin approach
`from torch import nn`

Is there any difference between these two styles of importing?